# Dequeuing script fails because of action on wp_enqueue_scripts in other functons.php snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove password strength meter (I read it is woocommerce, not wordpress based). I have a snippet for this, which works like a charm, with one exception - it conflicts with my 2nd snippet, which prevents dequeuing of this script. 1st snippet below:

```
// Remove password strength meter from checkout, registration and password recovery.
function wc_ninja_remove_password_strength() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );      
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength' );
```

I have additional add and remove actions in my 2nd snippet's function with wp_print_scripts and wp_print_head_scripts, but by testing I separated the ones causing problem and I show only these:

```
// Move render-blocking JavaScript.
function custom_clean_head() {    
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);  
   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_clean_head', 9999999 );
```

I tried deregistering script, password strength meter disappeared, but it caused a huge amount of javascript errors on page load.

Comment: have you tried adding and tuning the priority like this: `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength', 100 );`

Comment: I think the problem is with the second snippet of yours. Have you tried removing the first snippet altogether and testing if the JS errors still show up?

Comment: I tried `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength', 100 );` (actually priority 100 was a default one) and it didn't work. JS errors only show up when I deregister script in 1st snippet. Any of them works fine if run without other. I also tried replacing `wp_print_scripts` with `wp_head` but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, had to replace `wp_print_scripts` with `wp_enqueue_scripts` in the last line of 1st snippet.

It comes out that since Wordpress 3.3 (over 4 years ago) `wp_print_scripts` should not be used and replaced by `wp_enqueue_scripts` as I just did.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts

```
// Remove password strength meter from checkout, registration and password recovery.
function wc_ninja_remove_password_strength() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );      
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength');
```